# Date components day difference between two dates wrong for today and tomorrow

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, date, time, nsdatecomponents

I want to show "Today" or "Tomorrow" in a label if a due date is actually today or tomorrow, and show it in "dd-mm-yyy" format for the rest.

Everything works almost perfectly apart from the fact that (given that today is 7 Jun):

- If I set the due date to today (7 Jun) or tomorrow (8 Jun), the label is updated with the text "Today".
- If I set the due date to the day after tomorrow (9 Jun), it shows "Tomorrow" .

This is my code:

```
- (void)configureDueLabelForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell withChecklistItem:(ChecklistItem *)item
{
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1002];

    if (item.shouldRemind) {
        int difference = [self dateDiffrenceToDate:item.dueDate];
        if (difference == 0) {
            label.text = @"Today";
        } else if (difference == 1) {
            label.text = @"Tomorrow";
        } else {
            NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
           // [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
            [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
            label.text = [formatter stringFromDate:item.dueDate];
        }

    } else {
        label.text = @"";
    }
}

-(int)dateDiffrenceToDate:(NSDate *)dueDate
{
    // Manage Date Formation same for both dates
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate = dueDate;


    unsigned flags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *difference = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];

    int dayDiff = [difference day];

    return dayDiff;
}
```

I also tried:

```
//    NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
//    NSDate *endDate = dueDate;
//    
//    NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
//    
//    int numberOfDays = secondsBetween / 86400;
//    NSLog(@"numberofdays: %d", numberOfDays);
//
//    return numberOfDays;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW1

"... this method truncates the results of the calculation to the smallest unit supplied. For instance, if the fromDate: parameter corresponds to Jan 14, 2010 at 11:30 PM and the toDate: parameter corresponds to Jan 15, 2010 at 8:00 AM, there are only 8.5 hours between the two dates. If you ask for the number of days, you get 0, because 8.5 hours is less than 1 day. There may be situations where this should be 1 day. You have to decide which behavior your users expect in a particular case. If you do need to have a calculation that returns the number of days, calculated by the number of midnights between the two dates, you can use a category to NSCalendar similar to the one in Listing 13."

Comment: Ohh .. Now it makes sense .. Thank you .. is there any way that i can actually compare just the date and not the time?

Comment: Or calculate the hours till midnight as well as the hours till the due date. If hours till midnight is smaller, the due date is tomorrow.

Comment: On reflection, if you calculate to hours in the result, the truncation should occur at the hour level rather than the day level, and your problem goes away. Plus you don't have to worry about events happening right before or after midnight. Try and see!